# Eclipse awt error unhandled loop exception

Tags: java, eclipse

I wanna ask a question about ecliple(luna) swt error,
When i click view

[image: view] then click editor,the error always happen

Error log

[image: error log]

And if i close the view ,error will not happend

Can anyone if resolve this problem and can answer me

I've try imporve eclipse memory at ini file.
and change my editor to window builder.
but it is not work to me.
Hope can find answer ... 

Many thanks!

Comment: can you click "Show error log" and add that content to your question.

Comment: Which editor? Which view? Is it always the same one?